# Writing code with two aws lambda functions using the same python package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I made a aws serverless application with lambda and put to git with the structure is somewhat like this. I have two lambda functions `lambda1` and `lambda2` importing the same Python package `common_lib`.

```
common_lib/
├── __init__.py
└── utils.py
lambda1/
└── lambda_function.py
lambda2/
└── lambda_function.py
```

I made common_lib as a layer and import like this in lambda production:

In `lambda1/lambda_function.py` and `lambda2/lambda_function.py`:

```
import common_lib.utils
# ...
```

But my local code is a bit different because of the structure of the project:

In `lambda1/lambda_function.py` and `lambda2/lambda_function.py`:

```
import ..common_lib.utils
# ...
```

I want to make local code and production code to be the same.

So, how to people handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which IDE you are working you could add an extra path to have auto completion. You could to this snippet in VSCode in `.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "./common_lib"
    ]
}
```

which essentially tells the IDE to look into that directory as well. Be aware that is only to have auto completion if you would run the python code from your CLI, this would not work as the interpreter is not aware of the extra path.